# Can I specify to Castle Windsor which virtual methods to override in a class proxy?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I have many virtual methods in a class, but only one should be intercepted, Can I tell Castle Windsor to override only that method so I dont have to do validation in the Intercept method?

Edit:

I use the IKernelEvents.ComponentRegistered event to choose which types get the interceptor.

Comment: how about using a decorator instead of an interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to proxy just one method, use `IProxyHook` to pick which method you want to proxy.
2. If you're modifying `ComponentModel` (and adding interceptors or proxy hooks is one such operation) use `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`s for that. [See the docs](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx) for more in depth explanation.

Comment: Should I use this interface to change the 'ComponentModel.Implementation' for a proxy I created manually using DynamicProxy API with IProxyHook?

Comment: As the docs say, generally if you want to do modifications to ComponentModel do it in `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`